# Simplifying the sequence $(n-1)x_1+\cdots+(n-1)x_{n-1}$

Tags: algorithms, induction

### Background

I am currently working through *Concrete Mathematics* by Donald Knuth (1988) and in [Chapter 1, Exercise 9a](https://archive.org/embed/B-001-002-135), there is a part I do not understand:

$$(n-1)x_1+\cdots+(n-1)x_{n-1}$$

seems to simplify to just $n$ according to one of the answers for this exercise. How? The actual exercise is:

$$P(n): x_1\dots x_n\le \bigg(\frac{n(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1})}{n}\bigg)^n,\quad \text{if}\ x_1,\dots,x_n \ge 0.$$

By setting $x_n = \frac{(x_1 +\dots + x_{n-1})}{(n − 1)}$ , prove that $P(n)$ implies $P(n − 1)$ whenever $n \gt 1.$

### My Attempt

\begin{align}
&\bigg(\frac{(n-1)x_1+\cdots+(n-1)x_{n-1}+x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}}{n(n-1}\bigg)^n \\
&=\bigg(\frac{n(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1})}{n(n-1)}\bigg)^n\\
&=\bigg(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}\bigg)^n\\
\end{align}
Am I on the right track?

Comment: What are the $x_{i}$? Are they defined recursively? If so what is the rule? They look like free variables as written in the question.

Comment: Definitely "need be", please elaborate.

Comment: @openproblem clarified, sorry

Comment: @Deepak clarified, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the steps more carefully. The step you’re confused about is elaborated upon below:

$$\begin{align}
&(n-1)x_1 + \ldots + (n-1)x_{n-1} + x_1+\ldots + x_{n-1} \\
&=(n-1)(x_1+\ldots+x_{n-1})+1(x_1+\ldots + x_{n-1})\\
&= ((n-1)+1) (x_1+\ldots + x_{n-1})\\
&=n(x_1+\ldots + x_{n-1})
\end{align}$$

Exercises on  factorisation, simplification,  algebraic manipulation  can  help you see these things in one step.

And no, $(n-1)x_1 + \ldots (n-1)x_{n-1}$ doesn’t simplify to $n$. Rules of arithmetic don’t break simply because of presence of “$\ldots$”.

Comment: Thank you! But how did you combine the left part of the topmost equation to be just "((n-1)+1)"? If it's even possible to explain it even simpler...

Comment: And also, again in the topmost equation, the second x-term in the answer I attached in my question (labeled as "the steps") is xₙ₋₁ , rather than xₙ like you wrote, did you misread or is there an error in the solution I attached? And would that even make a difference for the final answer?

Comment: You can rearrange (finite) sums without worry because of the commutative property. So you can regroup the sum so that for each $x_i$, you're adding $(n-1)x_i$ to $x_i$. Which gives $x_i (n-1 + 1) = nx_i$ after one more grouping step.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks a lot for your answer, but I just can't see where the "+1" comes from?

Comment: Edited to show one  more step and to write n-1 instead of n in the subscript

Comment: Wow, I get it I think? Thanks again for your patience, and I will make sure to work through all the topics you suggested.